# how to select a custome dropdown option in Playwright UI test

Tags: html, testing, playwright, ui-testing, playwright-test

**I am doing end to end UI testing and when I try to select an option for Harmony web UI component (<ext-support_he-select>), playwright is not able to recognize the custome tag and it error out saying not a select option.**

And I am not able to record dropdown select option with **Headless Recorder** as well, could you please let me know if anybody has come across this kind of issue.

**HTML Select Code :**
{
<ext-support_he-select id="workspace-dropdown" class="basic-dropdown basic-workspace-dropdown below valid" aria-labelledby="workspace-label" role="combobox" current-value="" aria-controls="" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" tabindex="0" position="below" aria-activedescendant="option-14">

```
    <ext-support_he-option selected="" value="" aria-selected="true" class="selected" role="option" id="option-14" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="9"> Select a Workspace </ext-support_he-option>
  
         
    <ext-support_he-option value="accountPlans" aria-selected="false" role="option" id="option-15" aria-posinset="2" aria-setsize="9"> Account Plans </ext-support_he-option>
   
    <ext-support_he-option value="accounts" aria-selected="false" role="option" id="option-16" aria-posinset="3" aria-setsize="9"> Accounts </ext-support_he-option>
   
    <ext-support_he-option value="contacts" aria-selected="false" role="option" id="option-17" aria-posinset="4" aria-setsize="9"> Contacts </ext-support_he-option>
   
    <ext-support_he-option value="engagements" aria-selected="false" role="option" id="option-18" aria-posinset="5" aria-setsize="9"> Engagements </ext-support_he-option>
   
    <ext-support_he-option value="leads" aria-selected="false" role="option" id="option-19" aria-posinset="6" aria-setsize="9"> Leads </ext-support_he-option>
   
    <ext-support_he-option value="opportunities" aria-selected="false" role="option" id="option-20" aria-posinset="7" aria-setsize="9"> Opportunities </ext-support_he-option>
   
    <ext-support_he-option value="partners" aria-selected="false" role="option" id="option-21" aria-posinset="8" aria-setsize="9"> Partners </ext-support_he-option>
   
    <ext-support_he-option value="userProvisioning" aria-selected="false" role="option" id="option-22" aria-posinset="9" aria-setsize="9"> User Provisioning </ext-support_he-option>
  <!--fast-eovm3s:5-->
      </ext-support_he-select> }
```

Please refer UI screenshot given below.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use first click on the dropdown and the click on the required dropdown item.

```
await page.locator(#workspace-dropdown).Click();
await page.waitForSelector("xpath=//ext-support_he-option[@value='accounts'");
await page.locator("xpath=//ext-support_he-option[@value='accounts'").Click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I got that hint from my friend as well, and this works instead of using the "select option" call. Just I putting my code as a reference if someone wants to use this.

```
  var workSpaceDropdown = page.locator('#workspace-dropdown');
  await workSpaceDropdown.click();
  page.keyboard.press('ArrowDown');
```

please refer below for more details.
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-keyboard#keyboard-down